# How to repeat textview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

In my Activity I have to add 10 times the same TextView.

Is it possible to load the definition of textview from layout.xml and repeat it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class YourClassName extends Activity
{
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        // set activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.some_activity_layout);

        LinearLayout mainActivityLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // then see previous answer
        // loop n times {
            TextView yourTextView = _li.inflate(R.layout.text_view_layout, null);
            mainActivityLayout.addView(yourTextView);
        // } end loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      Textview text = new TextView(this);
      mainlayout.add(text);
}
```

Comment: @SamirMangroliya how we can do this with any loop.. i mean on button click

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read this article on reusing UI components: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html